# Detect rectangles drawn on an background image using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I’m trying to detect some rectangles (white colored) which is drawn on an image. (say using paint or some other image editing tool).
As I’m very much beginner to image processing I searched through net and OpenCV sample program to accomplish the job, but could not get it to working perfectly. I’m using OpenCV C++ library.

Algorithm that I’ve tried

```
cv::Mat src = cv::imread(argv[1]);
cv::Mat gray;
cv::cvtColor(src, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
meanStdDev(gray, mu, sigma);
cv::Mat bw;
cv::Canny(gray, bw, mu.val[0] - sigma.val[0], mu.val[0] + sigma.val[0]);
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::findContours(bw.clone(), contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

std::vector<cv::Point> approx;
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++){
cv::approxPolyDP(cv::Mat(contours[i]), approx, cv::arcLength(cv::Mat(contours[i]), true)*0.02, true);
if (approx.size() >= 4 && approx.size() <= 6)
Rect boundRect = boundingRect( Mat(approx) );
rectangle( dst, boundRect.tl(), boundRect.br(), Scalar(255,255,255), 1, 8, 0 );}
```

Only one rectangle is detected. Can you please guide me or some link for the same.

Input image:

[image]

Output image:

[image]

Comment: what is `i` (for example in `contours[i]`)?

Comment: I'm looping through the contours.size(), I've edited my earlier post. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: can you `std::cout << contours.size() << std::endl;`? Is there more than one contour found? Are you sure that `approx.size() <= 6` doesnt filter out many good contours? Did you play with that parameter? Post a sample input image please.

Comment: contours.size() 347. I've added a sample input image in my post

Comment: I guess there is too much distraction in the image, so most of the white rectangles will have additional structures in the canny image.

Comment: Is there anything we could do to overcome the same? other than trying with different image :)

Comment: in your code, did you forget the `{`s after the `if (approx.size() >= 4 && approx.size() <= 6)` case?

Comment: :) I can assure you that there is no programming error. The code i pasted is the hint of algorithm copied from source code.

Comment: does not compile since `if (approx.size() >= 4 && approx.size() <= 6)
Rect boundRect = boundingRect( Mat(approx) );
rectangle( dst, boundRect.tl(), boundRect.br(), Scalar(255,255,255), 1, 8, 0 );`  declares `boundingRect` in the if-block and `rectangle` is outside of the if-block. So boundRect isn't known to the rectangle function.

Comment: or did you declare `boundRect` once more outside of the block? Then the in-block declaration is probably wrong since you'd never use the result of cv::boundingRect then.

Answer (score 2):

I could not compile your code sample because there boundRect is declared within the if-block but rectangle drawing (trying to access boundRect) is outside of the if-block, so I adjusted your code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cv::Mat src = cv::imread("C:/StackOverflow/Input/rectangles.png");
    cv::Mat dst = src.clone();

    cv::Mat gray;
    cv::cvtColor(src, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    // ADDED: missing declaration of mu and sigma
    cv::Scalar mu, sigma;
    meanStdDev(gray, mu, sigma);
    cv::Mat bw;
    cv::Canny(gray, bw, mu.val[0] - sigma.val[0], mu.val[0] + sigma.val[0]);

    // ADDED: displaying the canny output
    cv::imshow("canny", bw);


    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    cv::findContours(bw.clone(), contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    std::vector<cv::Point> approx;
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++){
        cv::approxPolyDP(cv::Mat(contours[i]), approx, cv::arcLength(cv::Mat(contours[i]), true)*0.02, true);
        if (approx.size() >= 4 && approx.size() <= 6)
        {
            // ADDED: brackets around both lines belonging to the if-block
            cv::Rect boundRect = cv::boundingRect(cv::Mat(approx));
            cv::rectangle(dst, boundRect.tl(), boundRect.br(), cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255), 3, 8, 0);
        }

    }

    // ADDED: displaying input and results
    cv::imshow("input", src);
    cv::imshow("dst", dst);
    cv::imwrite("C:/StackOverflow/Output/rectangles.png", dst);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

with your input image I do get this output:

[image]

which is probably not what you expected. See the canny output image (it is always good to have a look at intermediate results for visual debugging!), there are just too many structures in the image and contours will cover all of these, so there are some that will be approximated to polynomes with 4 to 6 elements.

Instead you'll have to become a bit smarter. You could try to extract straight lines with cv::HoughLinesP and connect those lines. Or you could try to segment the image first by finding white areas (if your rectangles are always white).

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cv::Mat src = cv::imread("C:/StackOverflow/Input/rectangles.png");
    cv::Mat dst = src.clone();

    cv::Mat gray;
    cv::cvtColor(src, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    cv::Mat mask;
    // find "white" pixel
    cv::inRange(src, cv::Scalar(230, 230, 230), cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255), mask);
    cv::imshow("mask", mask);

    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    cv::findContours(mask, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    std::vector<cv::Point> approx;
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++){
        cv::approxPolyDP(cv::Mat(contours[i]), approx, cv::arcLength(cv::Mat(contours[i]), true)*0.02, true);
        if (approx.size() >= 4 && approx.size() <= 6)
        {
            cv::Rect boundRect = cv::boundingRect(cv::Mat(approx));
            cv::rectangle(dst, boundRect.tl(), boundRect.br(), cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255), 1, 8, 0);
        }
    }


    cv::imshow("input", src);
    cv::imshow("dst", dst);
    cv::imwrite("C:/StackOverflow/Output/rectangles2.png", dst);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

gives this result:

[image]

As you can see, there are other bright regions near white, too. The polynom approximation does not help much, too.

Comment: Cool @Micka, Thats indeed smarter. I need to expand the range to get the desire result cv::inRange(src, cv::Scalar(190, 190, 190), cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255), mask); But as you said, robustness of this solution is a question.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's easier to segment a color (even white) in HSV space. With appropriate thresholds:

```
inRange(hsv, Scalar(0, 0, 220), Scalar(180, 30, 255), mask);
```

where we don't care about the Hue, and keep only low Saturation and high Value, I get:

[image]

Then you can easily find connected components, and discard blobs smaller than a threshold `th_blob_size`. Resulting rectangles are (in green):

[image]

You can eventually apply other filtering stage to account for more difficult situations, but for this image removing small blobs is enough. Please post other images if you need something more robust in general.

Code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat3b img = imread("path_to_image");

    int th_blob_size = 100;

    Mat3b hsv;
    cvtColor(img, hsv, COLOR_BGR2HSV);

    Mat1b mask;
    inRange(hsv, Scalar(0, 0, 220), Scalar(180, 30, 255), mask);

    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    findContours(mask.clone(), contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    Mat3b res = img.clone();
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i)
    {
        // Remove small blobs
        if (contours[i].size() < th_blob_size)
        {
            continue;
        }

        Rect box = boundingRect(contours[i]);
        rectangle(res, box, Scalar(0,255,0), 1);
    }

    imshow("Result", res);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The approach of segmenting a color in the picture is failing when the background color and contour color is same. :(

Comment: Well, 1) please provide an image for that case. There is room for a lot of improvements. 2) Why don't you make your rectangles a bright green 0,255,0, so that the chances to have it in the image are nearly 0? Also, an image with rectangles drawn without anti-aliasing or jpeg compression would be much much much better

Comment: Added an image example

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are only finding one contour or are you only *drawing* one contour? It doesn't look like you are looping in the drawing routine so you will only ever draw the first one that is found.

I have a blog, long since dead, that may provide you some good direction on this: http://workingwithcomputervision.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/game-player-step-2-finding-game-board.html

Should the link die I believe this is the most relevant part of the article which relates to drawing contours:

```
//Draw contours
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
Scalar color = Scalar(0, 255, 0);
drawContours(drawing, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point());
}
```

I notice you are using bounding rectangles for the drawing. Here is an alternative drawing routine, again from the above link, that does this:

```
Rect bounds;
Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(purpleOnly.size(), CV_8UC3);
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
   if (arcLength(contours[i], true) > 500){
       Rect temp = boundingRect(contours[i]);
       rectangle(drawing, temp, Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2, 8);
       if (j == 0) {
           bounds = temp;
       } else {
           bounds = bounds | temp;
       }
       j++;
   }
}
```

Note that I also do some checks on the size of the contour to filter out noise.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the code i pasted is the algorithm that i used but in actual running code i looped for all contours.size().

Comment: Sorry not much help :( seems it draws only the bounding rectangles. I guess detecting the rectangles is the problem than drawing it back.

Comment: Oh well, been a while since I've looked at OpenCV but the question fell in my lap as I was browsing and I thought this would cover it. Was also going to suggest looking at interim results as @Micka has, you gain a lot from doing that, but didn't have time. Don't forget to upvote / accept his answer if it covers your resolves your problem well enough.

Comment: well Micka's sol has given me a result which is indeed good in particular case but soon as added more rectangles to relatively white background it fails to detect. :(. So definitely a upvote but i'm afraid cant accept it.

Comment: No worries, up to you when or if to accept an answer, just a gentle reminder just in case. :D